# Subscript beneath multiple words

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

How do I achieve this subscript beneath `arg max`?

[image: desired]
[image]

I tried a couple of things and got mixed results.

```
\mathrm{\mathbf{v_2}} &=& \mathrm{arg}\max_{\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}\perp\mathrm{\mathbf{v_1}}|\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|=1}|W\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|\\[5pt]
\mathrm{\mathbf{v_3}} &=& \text{arg max}_{\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}\perp \mathrm{\mathbf{v_1}},\mathrm{\mathbf{v_2}}|\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|=1}|W\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|
```

[image: bad res]
[image]

Comment: Apologies the image upload hasn't worked, im trying to fix it.

Comment: There are problems with Imgur, but SE management hopes they'll be solved soon.

Comment: Most of your `\mathrm` commands do nothing at all, because `\mathXX` commands are not “cumulative” like `\textXX` commands. The only sensible one is `\mathrm{arg}`, although it doesn't help with the solution, which is doing `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the `argmax` using `DeclareMathOperator` command and use:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\begin{document}
    \[\argmax_{v\perp v_1\lvert v\rvert=1}\lvert Wv\rvert\]
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: I think usage of `underset` is wrong. Not only should you use `_` after an operator, but it also changes the spacing.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman you mean the first/second/both part(s)?

Comment: I mean that underset was not made for such situations

Comment: No! `\underset` is *wrong* for this application.

Comment: @egreg could you tell me when we must use `\underset` and when not? Also, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an operator. It can be set with `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath`. I also used `\DeclarePairedDelimeter` from `mathtools`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\newcommand{\bfv}{\mathbf{v}}

\begin{document}

    Displayed:
    \[
        \bfv_3=\argmax_{\mathrm{\bfv}\perp\bfv_1,\bfv_2,\;\abs{\bfv}=1}=\abs*{A\bfv}
    \]
    and inline
    $\bfv_3=\argmax_{\mathrm{\bfv}\perp\bfv_1,\bfv_2,\;\abs{\bfv}=1}=\abs*{A\bfv}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Huhh I see, initially when I tried to insert `subscript` with `_` it resulted as inline math. Hence, I restored back using hard-coded  `\underset{...}{...}` instead. Now I understand.

Comment: I'd not use `\bfv`, but probably define a semantic command for all vectors. Anyway, `\mathrm{\bfv}` is wasting tokens, because it behaves no different from `\bfv`.

Comment: @egreg just to make code shorter. But thanks for pointing out that mathrm has no effect: I use unicode-math and so not aquatinted with behaviour of this commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests you're using `eqnarray`. Don't. Also, `\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}` is exactly the same as `\mathbf{v}` (math alphabet commands are not “cumulative”).

Subscripts to vectors should not be bold, so they have to be set outside the scope of `\mathbf`.

I suggest two realizations of the formula, one with `\substack` that in my opinion is better. I also show how to use `align` instead of `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % semantic for vectors

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\vect{v}_2 &=
  \argmax_{\substack{\vect{v}\perp\vect{v}_1 \\ |\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|=1}}
  \lvert W\vect{v}\rvert
\\
\vect{v}_2 &=
  \argmax_{\vect{v}\perp\vect{v}_1, |\mathrm{\mathbf{v}}|=1}
  \lvert W\vect{v}\rvert
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]